# How could I open a file via the function parameter in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to open a file via a function's parameter. The function I'm trying to make is going to be a multi-purpose one that will work with different files.

```
def word_editor(open(filename, 'f'))
```

Would this be the correct way to open it? `filename` will represent whatever file I am opening.

Comment: why don't you pass the file name as a parameter and open the file within the function?

Comment: @Vaulstein: Because then it can't take file-likes.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I have a suspicion that this won't matter to OP.

Comment: You cannot have a function call in the function definition header. Only formal parameters are allowed in the parentheses.

Comment: what @Vaulstein says might be what I need to do, mainly because once i open which ever file is specified I need to then take particular parts of it and put it into tuples

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want this.

```
def test(file_object):
     for line in file_object:
         print(line) 

test(open('test.txt','r'))
```

Output:

```
line #1
line #2
....  
....
line #n
```

---

Alternatively, you can pass filename as a parameter of the function, like below:

```
def test(file_name):
    with open(file_name,'a+') as f:  
         # do whatever you want to do. 

test('your_file.txt')
```

Comment: This is somewhat what i was trying to do except, I mainly wanted it to open the file in the function via the parameter and allow me to edit it

Comment: Then just send the file name as a parameter and open it in the function...

Comment: Positional parameters are file_name (1) and open-type(2)? Keyword arguments are encoding, etc.?

Answer (score 1):

Defining any function you should list the arguments' names only. That's why your line `def word_editor(open(filename, 'f'))` can't be correct. If you want to work with file like objects, you should pass it as an argument like this:

```
def word_editor(fl):
    text = fl.read()
    print(text)
```

After that you can use this function like this:

```
f1 = open("file1.txt", "r")
word_editor(f1)
f1.close()

with open("file2.txt", "r") as f2:
    word_editor(f2)
```